# Why is my occlusion culling failed with Three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl, webgl2, occlusion-culling

First I knew that Three.js does not have official support for occlusion culling. However, I thought it's possible to do occlusion culling in an offscreen canvas and copy the result back to my Three.js WebGLCanvas.

Basically, I want to transform this [demo](https://tsherif.github.io/webgl2examples/occlusion.html)
to a Three.JS demo. I use Three.js to create everything, and in a synced offscreen canvas, I test occlusion culling against each bounding box. If any bounding box is occluded, I turn off the visibility of that sphere in the main canvas. Those are what I did in this snippet. but I don't know why it failed to occlude any sphere.

I think a possible issue might be coming from calculating the ModelViewProjection matrix of the bounding box, but I don't see anything wrong. Could somebody please help?

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, light;
var spheres = [];
var NUM_SPHERES, occludedSpheres = 0;
var gl;
var boundingBoxPositions;
var boundingBoxProgram, boundingBoxArray, boundingBoxModelMatrixLocation, viewProjMatrixLocation;
var viewMatrix, projMatrix;
var firstRender = true;

var sphereCountElement = document.getElementById("num-spheres");
var occludedSpheresElement = document.getElementById("num-invisible-spheres");

// depth sort variables
var sortPositionA = new THREE.Vector3();
var sortPositionB = new THREE.Vector3();
var sortModelView = new THREE.Matrix4();

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    scene.add( light );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    // set up offscreen canvas
  
    var offscreenCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    gl = offscreenCanvas.getContext('webgl2');
    
    if ( !gl ) {
      console.error("WebGL 2 not available");
      document.body.innerHTML = "This example requires WebGL 2 which is unavailable on this system."
    }
    
    // define spheres

    var GRID_DIM = 6;
    var GRID_OFFSET = GRID_DIM / 2 - 0.5;
    NUM_SPHERES = GRID_DIM * GRID_DIM;
    sphereCountElement.innerHTML = NUM_SPHERES;

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(20, 64, 64);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0xff0000,
        specular: 0x050505,
        shininess: 50,
        emissive: 0x000000
    } );
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    for ( var i = 0; i < NUM_SPHERES; i ++ ) {
    
      var x = Math.floor(i / GRID_DIM) - GRID_OFFSET;
      var z = i % GRID_DIM - GRID_OFFSET;
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      spheres.push(mesh);
      scene.add(mesh);

      mesh.position.set(x * 35, 0, z * 35);
      mesh.userData.query = gl.createQuery();
      mesh.userData.queryInProgress = false;
      mesh.userData.occluded = false;
      
    }
    
    //////////////////////////
    // WebGL code
    //////////////////////////
    
    // boundingbox shader
    
    var boundingBoxVSource =  document.getElementById("vertex-boundingBox").text.trim();
    var boundingBoxFSource =  document.getElementById("fragment-boundingBox").text.trim();
    var boundingBoxVertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(boundingBoxVertexShader, boundingBoxVSource);
    gl.compileShader(boundingBoxVertexShader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(boundingBoxVertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(boundingBoxVertexShader));
    }

    var boundingBoxFragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(boundingBoxFragmentShader, boundingBoxFSource);
    gl.compileShader(boundingBoxFragmentShader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(boundingBoxFragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(boundingBoxFragmentShader));
    }

    boundingBoxProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(boundingBoxProgram, boundingBoxVertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(boundingBoxProgram, boundingBoxFragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(boundingBoxProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(boundingBoxProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(boundingBoxProgram));
    }
    
    // uniform location
    
    boundingBoxModelMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(boundingBoxProgram, "uModel");
    viewProjMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(boundingBoxProgram, "uViewProj");

    // vertex location
    
    boundingBoxPositions = computeBoundingBoxPositions(geometry.boundingBox);

    boundingBoxArray = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(boundingBoxArray);

    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, boundingBoxPositions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

    gl.bindVertexArray(null);

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function depthSort(a, b) {
    sortPositionA.copy(a.position);
    sortPositionB.copy(b.position);

    sortModelView.copy(viewMatrix).multiply(a.matrix);
    sortPositionA.applyMatrix4(sortModelView);
    sortModelView.copy(viewMatrix).multiply(b.matrix);
    sortPositionB.applyMatrix4(sortModelView);
    return sortPositionB[2] - sortPositionA[2];
}

function render() {

    var timer = Date.now() * 0.0001;
    camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 250;
    camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 250;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    light.position.copy( camera.position );
    
    occludedSpheres = 0;
    
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);
    gl.depthMask(true);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
    if (!firstRender) {
    viewMatrix = camera.matrixWorldInverse.clone();
    projMatrix = camera.projectionMatrix.clone();
    var viewProjMatrix = projMatrix.multiply(viewMatrix);

    spheres.sort(depthSort);

    // for occlusion test
          
    gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false);
    gl.depthMask(false);
    gl.useProgram(boundingBoxProgram);
    gl.bindVertexArray(boundingBoxArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_SPHERES; i ++) {
          
        spheres[i].visible = true;
        spheres[i].rotation.y += 0.003;

        var sphereData = spheres[i].userData;

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(boundingBoxModelMatrixLocation, false, spheres[i].matrix.elements);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(viewProjMatrixLocation, false, viewProjMatrix.elements);

        // check query results here (will be from previous frame)
              
        if (sphereData.queryInProgress && gl.getQueryParameter(sphereData.query, gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE)) {
              
            sphereData.occluded = !gl.getQueryParameter(sphereData.query, gl.QUERY_RESULT);
            if (sphereData.occluded) occludedSpheres ++;
            sphereData.queryInProgress = false;
                
       }

       // Query is initiated here by drawing the bounding box of the sphere
              
       if (!sphereData.queryInProgress) {
              
           gl.beginQuery(gl.ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED_CONSERVATIVE, sphereData.query);
           gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, boundingBoxPositions.length / 3);
           gl.endQuery(gl.ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED_CONSERVATIVE);
           sphereData.queryInProgress = true;
                
       }

       if (sphereData.occluded) {
              
            spheres[i].visible = false;
                
       }
            
    }
          
        occludedSpheresElement.innerHTML = occludedSpheres;
          
    }
        
    firstRender = false;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function computeBoundingBoxPositions(box) {

    var dimension = box.max.sub(box.min);
    var width = dimension.x;
    var height = dimension.y;
    var depth = dimension.z;
    var x = box.min.x;
    var y = box.min.y;
    var z = box.min.z;

    var fbl = {x: x,         y: y,          z: z + depth};
    var fbr = {x: x + width, y: y,          z: z + depth};
    var ftl = {x: x,         y: y + height, z: z + depth};
    var ftr = {x: x + width, y: y + height, z: z + depth};
    var bbl = {x: x,         y: y,          z: z };
    var bbr = {x: x + width, y: y,          z: z };
    var btl = {x: x,         y: y + height, z: z };
    var btr = {x: x + width, y: y + height, z: z };

    var positions = new Float32Array([
      //front
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,

      //right
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,

      //back
      fbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,

      //left
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,

      //top
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,

      //bottom
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
    ]);

  return positions;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r125/three.js"></script>
<div id="occlusion-controls">
  Spheres: <span id="num-spheres"></span><br> Culled spheres: <span id="num-invisible-spheres"></span><br>
</div>

<script type="x-shader/vs" id="vertex-boundingBox">#version 300 es
layout(std140, column_major) uniform;
layout(location=0) in vec4 position;
uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uViewProj;
void main() {
  gl_Position = uViewProj * uModel * position;
}
</script>
<script type="x-shader/vf" id="fragment-boundingBox">#version 300 es
precision highp float;
layout(std140, column_major) uniform;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main() {
  fragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, these are the issues I found.

1. you need to write to the depth buffer (otherwise how would anything occlude?)

   so remove `gl.depthMask(false)`
2. you need to `gl.flush` the `OffscreenCanvas` because being offscreen, one is not automatically added for you. I found this out by using a normal canvas and adding it to the page. I also turned on drawing by commenting out `gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false)` just to double check that your boxes are drawn correctly. I noticed that when I got something kind of working it behaved differently when I switched back to the offscreen canvas. I found the same different behavior if I didn't add the normal canvas to the page. Adding in the `gl.flush` fixed the different behavior.
3. `depthSort` was not working

   I checked this by changing the shader to use a color and I passed in `i / NUM_SPHERES` as the color which made it clear they were not being sorted. The issue was this

   ```
   return sortPositionB[2] - sortPositionA[2];
   ```

   needs to be

   ```
   return sortPositionB.z - sortPositionA.z;
   ```

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, light;
var spheres = [];
var NUM_SPHERES, occludedSpheres = 0;
var gl;
var boundingBoxPositions;
var boundingBoxProgram, boundingBoxArray, boundingBoxModelMatrixLocation, viewProjMatrixLocation;
var viewMatrix, projMatrix;
var firstRender = true;

var sphereCountElement = document.getElementById("num-spheres");
var occludedSpheresElement = document.getElementById("num-invisible-spheres");

// depth sort variables
var sortPositionA = new THREE.Vector3();
var sortPositionB = new THREE.Vector3();
var sortModelView = new THREE.Matrix4();

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    scene.add( light );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    // set up offscreen canvas
  
    var offscreenCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    //var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    //offscreenCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    //offscreenCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    //document.body.appendChild(offscreenCanvas);
    gl = offscreenCanvas.getContext('webgl2');
    
    if ( !gl ) {
      console.error("WebGL 2 not available");
      document.body.innerHTML = "This example requires WebGL 2 which is unavailable on this system."
    }
    
    // define spheres

    var GRID_DIM = 6;
    var GRID_OFFSET = GRID_DIM / 2 - 0.5;
    NUM_SPHERES = GRID_DIM * GRID_DIM;
    sphereCountElement.innerHTML = NUM_SPHERES;

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(20, 64, 64);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0xff0000,
        specular: 0x050505,
        shininess: 50,
        emissive: 0x000000
    } );
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    for ( var i = 0; i < NUM_SPHERES; i ++ ) {
    
      var x = Math.floor(i / GRID_DIM) - GRID_OFFSET;
      var z = i % GRID_DIM - GRID_OFFSET;
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      spheres.push(mesh);
      scene.add(mesh);

      mesh.position.set(x * 35, 0, z * 35);
      mesh.userData.query = gl.createQuery();
      mesh.userData.queryInProgress = false;
      mesh.userData.occluded = false;
      
    }
    
    //////////////////////////
    // WebGL code
    //////////////////////////
    
    // boundingbox shader
    
    var boundingBoxVSource =  document.getElementById("vertex-boundingBox").text.trim();
    var boundingBoxFSource =  document.getElementById("fragment-boundingBox").text.trim();
    var boundingBoxVertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(boundingBoxVertexShader, boundingBoxVSource);
    gl.compileShader(boundingBoxVertexShader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(boundingBoxVertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(boundingBoxVertexShader));
    }

    var boundingBoxFragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(boundingBoxFragmentShader, boundingBoxFSource);
    gl.compileShader(boundingBoxFragmentShader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(boundingBoxFragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(boundingBoxFragmentShader));
    }

    boundingBoxProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(boundingBoxProgram, boundingBoxVertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(boundingBoxProgram, boundingBoxFragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(boundingBoxProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(boundingBoxProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(boundingBoxProgram));
    }
    
    // uniform location
    
    boundingBoxModelMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(boundingBoxProgram, "uModel");
    viewProjMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(boundingBoxProgram, "uViewProj");

    // vertex location
    
    boundingBoxPositions = computeBoundingBoxPositions(geometry.boundingBox);

    boundingBoxArray = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(boundingBoxArray);

    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, boundingBoxPositions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

    gl.bindVertexArray(null);

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function depthSort(a, b) {
    sortPositionA.copy(a.position);
    sortPositionB.copy(b.position);

    sortModelView.copy(viewMatrix).multiply(a.matrix);
    sortPositionA.applyMatrix4(sortModelView);
    sortModelView.copy(viewMatrix).multiply(b.matrix);
    sortPositionB.applyMatrix4(sortModelView);
    return sortPositionB.z - sortPositionA.z;
}

function render() {

    var timer = Date.now() * 0.0001;
    camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 250;
    camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 250;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    light.position.copy( camera.position );
    
    occludedSpheres = 0;
    
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);
    gl.depthMask(true);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
    if (!firstRender) {
    viewMatrix = camera.matrixWorldInverse.clone();
    projMatrix = camera.projectionMatrix.clone();
    var viewProjMatrix = projMatrix.multiply(viewMatrix);

    spheres.sort(depthSort);

    // for occlusion test
          
    gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false);
    //gl.depthMask(false);
    gl.useProgram(boundingBoxProgram);
    gl.bindVertexArray(boundingBoxArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_SPHERES; i ++) {
          
        spheres[i].visible = true;
        spheres[i].rotation.y += 0.003;

        var sphereData = spheres[i].userData;

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(boundingBoxModelMatrixLocation, false, spheres[i].matrix.elements);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(viewProjMatrixLocation, false, viewProjMatrix.elements);
        gl.uniform4f(gl.getUniformLocation(boundingBoxProgram, 'color'),
          i / NUM_SPHERES, 0, 0, 1);

        // check query results here (will be from previous frame)
              
        if (sphereData.queryInProgress && gl.getQueryParameter(sphereData.query, gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE)) {
              
            sphereData.occluded = !gl.getQueryParameter(sphereData.query, gl.QUERY_RESULT);
            if (sphereData.occluded) occludedSpheres ++;
            sphereData.queryInProgress = false;
                
       }

       // Query is initiated here by drawing the bounding box of the sphere
              
       if (!sphereData.queryInProgress) {
              
           gl.beginQuery(gl.ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED_CONSERVATIVE, sphereData.query);
           gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, boundingBoxPositions.length / 3);
           gl.endQuery(gl.ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED_CONSERVATIVE);
           sphereData.queryInProgress = true;
                
       }

       if (sphereData.occluded) {
              
            spheres[i].visible = false;
                
       }
            
    }
    gl.flush();
          
        occludedSpheresElement.innerHTML = occludedSpheres;
          
    }
        
    firstRender = false;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function computeBoundingBoxPositions(box) {

    var dimension = box.max.sub(box.min);
    var width = dimension.x;
    var height = dimension.y;
    var depth = dimension.z;
    var x = box.min.x;
    var y = box.min.y;
    var z = box.min.z;

    var fbl = {x: x,         y: y,          z: z + depth};
    var fbr = {x: x + width, y: y,          z: z + depth};
    var ftl = {x: x,         y: y + height, z: z + depth};
    var ftr = {x: x + width, y: y + height, z: z + depth};
    var bbl = {x: x,         y: y,          z: z };
    var bbr = {x: x + width, y: y,          z: z };
    var btl = {x: x,         y: y + height, z: z };
    var btr = {x: x + width, y: y + height, z: z };

    var positions = new Float32Array([
      //front
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,

      //right
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,

      //back
      fbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,

      //left
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,

      //top
      ftl.x, ftl.y, ftl.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      btl.x, btl.y, btl.z,
      ftr.x, ftr.y, ftr.z,
      btr.x, btr.y, btr.z,

      //bottom
      bbl.x, bbl.y, bbl.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      fbl.x, fbl.y, fbl.z,
      bbr.x, bbr.y, bbr.z,
      fbr.x, fbr.y, fbr.z,
    ]);

  return positions;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r125/three.js"></script>
<div id="occlusion-controls">
  Spheres: <span id="num-spheres"></span><br> Culled spheres: <span id="num-invisible-spheres"></span><br>
</div>

<script type="x-shader/vs" id="vertex-boundingBox">#version 300 es
layout(std140, column_major) uniform;
layout(location=0) in vec4 position;
uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uViewProj;
void main() {
  gl_Position = uViewProj * uModel * position;
}
</script>
<script type="x-shader/vf" id="fragment-boundingBox">#version 300 es
precision highp float;
layout(std140, column_major) uniform;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main() {
  fragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
</script>
```