# Optimization of model display

Tags: three.js

I have a set of models (fbx) generated using SW Visualize. Each model contains a large number of meshes representing which parts (for example, rivets, bolts, washers).
Since the models are uploaded using SW Visualize they are very detailed, for example a bolt contains 5000 triangles, a rivet - 32000 triangles.
There is no point in displaying them all the time. In most cases, they are not visible because they are inside the model, or they are blocked by other objects.

Is there a mechanism in three.js that will disable the display of meshes if they are not visible (they are in the rendering zone but are overlapped by other objects)?

Answer (score 0):

> *...Is there a mechanism in three.js that will disable the display of
> meshes if they are not visible...*

Yes, `frustumCulled`, by default is set `true` which causes the object to not be rendered when it is not in the frustum of the camera.

But, if I understood correctly, these two objects are in the frustum of the camera, but one *covers* the other.

> *...(they are in the rendering zone but are overlapped by other
> objects)...*

So both will be rendered. Frustum culling helps to exclude objects outside the frustum, but it doesn't handle occlusion within the frustum.

There is some work on occlusion in webGL2

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15450

But I don't know at what stage the work on it is and how advanced it is, maybe the Author (who visits here sometimes) will answer you.

Besides, you can consider `LOD` (level of details)...

```
const lod = new THREE.LOD();

//Create spheres with 3 levels of detail and create new LOD levels for them
for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    const geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 10, 3 - i )
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    lod.addLevel( mesh, i * 75 );
}
scene.add( lod );
```

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod

... or play with `renderOrder`

You should also take a look at this advanced example:

[Why is my occlusion culling failed with Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65976999/why-is-my-occlusion-culling-failed-with-three-js)